# Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:JSFTut' did not find a matching property

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I am getting following error, when I run the demo JSF application on the console

```
[SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:JSFTut' did not find a matching property.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of ["SetPropertiesRule" warning message when starting Tomcat from Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104854/setpropertiesrule-warning-message-when-starting-tomcat-from-eclipse)

Answer (score 192, accepted):

This is not an error. This is a *warning*. The difference is pretty huge. This particular warning basically means that the `<Context>` element in Tomcat's `server.xml` contains an unknown attribute `source` and that Tomcat doesn't know what to do with this attribute and therefore will ignore it.

Eclipse WTP adds a custom attribute `source` to the project related `<Context>` element in the `server.xml` of Tomcat which identifies the source of the context (the actual project in the workspace which is deployed to the particular server). This way Eclipse can correlate the deployed webapplication with an project in the workspace. Since Tomcat version 6.0.16, any unspecified XML tags and attributes in the `server.xml` will produce a warning during Tomcat's startup, even though there is [no DTD nor XSD](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Miscellaneous#Q10) for `server.xml`.

Just ignore it. Your web project is fine. It should run fine. This issue is completely unrelated to JSF.

Comment: You can add this to your logging.properties to suppress warnings while reading your config: 
org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.level = SEVERE

Comment: I've noticed that if you have the server.xml file open it does not add the context back in. I just stopped the server and closed the server.xml file then re-added the project. THought I would mentioned it in case anyone else runs into the same problem.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104854/setpropertiesrule-warning-message-when-starting-tomcat-from-eclipse) thread actually offers a working answer. It gets rid of the warning. :)

Comment: (same for log4j.properties - 1.2.17) : `log4j.logger.org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester = ERROR`

Comment: For me the warning was an indication of an error - my project did not get deployed. The context attributes in Tomcat's server.xml was a hint - after deleting the eclipse-generated attributes and re-deploying from Eclipse I got one step further - now Eclipse showed me a good old popup with the real error.

Answer (score 12):

Remove the project from the server from the Server View. Then run the project under the same server.

The problem is as @BalusC told corrupt of server.xml of tomcat which is configured in the eclipse. So when you do the above process server.xml will be recreated .

Comment: My tomcat instance started up pretty quick one day (unusually), and looking at logs I noticed same message the poster had ... I tried cleaning and restarting server to no avail. Removing and then re-Adding the project to the Server helped as arvindwill recommended.

Answer (score 4):

I thought I'd add that for Tomcat 7.x, `<Context>` is not in the `server.xml`, but in the `context.xml`.  Removing and re-adding the project did not seem to help my similar issue, which was a web.xml issue, which I found out by checking the `context.xml` which had this line in the `<Context>` section:

`<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>`

The solution in [WARNING: Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:appname' did not find a matching property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278009/warning-setting-property-source-to-org-eclipse-jst-jee-serverappname-did-n) brought me closer to my answer, as the change of publishing into a separate XML did resolve the error reported above for me, but unfortunately it generated a second error that I'm still investigating.

`WARNING: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:myproject' did not find a matching property.`

Answer (score 4):

I have faced the similar issue. Steps to resolve this.

1. Remove the project from server
2. Give clean and build for the entire project
3. Delete the server
4. Use Run as to deploy and run the project

Hope this works for you too.

Answer (score 3):

In regards to setting the logging.properties value

`org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.level = SEVERE`

... if you're running an embedded tomcat server in eclipse, the `logging.properties` file used by default is the JDK default at `%JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/logging.properties`

If you want to use a different logging.properties file (e.g. in the tomcat server's `conf` directory), this needs to be set via the `java.util.logging.config.file` system property. e.g. to use the logging properties defined in the file `c:\java\apache-tomcat-7.0.54\conf\eclipse-logging.properties`, add this to the VM argument list:

`-Djava.util.logging.config.file="c:\java\apache-tomcat-7.0.54\conf\eclipse-logging.properties"`

(double-click on the server icon, click 'Open launch configuration', select the Arguments tab, then enter this in the 'VM arguments' text box)

You might also find it useful to add the VM argument

`-Djava.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format="%1$tc %4$s %3$s %5$s%n"`

as well, which will then include the source logger name in the output, which should make it easier to determine which logger to throttle in the logging.properties file (as per http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.html )

Answer (score 2):

#### Update to the latest release

Since [this commit](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/commit/d7fa05ab014d97ad02e5704343d1c7c587956eac), this is is fixed in the development version of Tomcat.  And now in released versions 9.0.13, 8.5.35, and 7.0.92.

From the 9.0.13 [changelog](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/changelog.html#Tomcat_9.0.13_(markt)):

> Ignore an attribute named source on Context elements provided by StandardContext. This is to suppress warnings generated by the Eclipse / Tomcat integration provided by Eclipse. Based on a patch by mdfst13. (markt)

There are similar entries in the [7.0.92](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/changelog.html#Tomcat_7.0.92_(violetagg)) and [8.5.35](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/changelog.html#Tomcat_8.5.35_(markt)) changelogs.

The effect of this change is to suppress a warning when a `source` attribute is declared on a `Context` element in either server.xml or a context.xml.  Since those are the two places that Eclipse puts such an attribute, that fixes this particular issue.

**TL;DR**:  update to the latest Tomcat version in its branch, e.g. 9.0.13 or newer.

Answer (score -1):

Please check if any jar files missing particularly jars are may have been taken as locally, so put into lib folder then create the WAR file

Answer (score -1):

This is simple solution for this warning:

> You can change the eclipse tomcat server configuration.  Open the
>   server view, double click on you server to open server configuration. 
>   There is a **server Option** Tab. inside that tab click check Box to
>   activate "**Publish module contents to separate XML files**".

Finally, restart your server, the message must disappear.