# WARNING: Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:appname' did not find a matching property

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee

When trying to run my app with eclipse/linux on apache tomcat on my local host
the application runs fine but, I got the following warning:

> WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:appname' did not find a matching property.

any ideas what does this warning means, how to resolve it?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Despite this question being rather old, I had to deal with a similar warning and wanted to share what I found out.

First of all this is a *warning* and not an *error*. So there is no need to worry too much about it. Basically it means, that Tomcat does not know what to do with the `source` attribute from context.

This `source` attribute is set by Eclipse (or to be more specific the Eclipse Web Tools Platform) to the `server.xml` file of Tomcat to match the running application to a project in workspace.

Tomcat generates a warning for every unknown markup in the `server.xml` (i.e. the `source` attribute) and this is the source of the warning. You can safely ignore it.

Comment: It is misleading to say that you can safely ignore it, unless the app is actually loading.  This may be the first symptom of what ultimately causes the app not to be loaded.

Comment: @CodeMed: it really is quite common and harmless.

Answer (score 27):

You can change the eclipse tomcat server configuration.
Open the server view, double click on you server to open server configuration.
Then click to activate "Publish module contents to separate XML files".
Finally, restart your server, the message must disappear.

Source:
http://www.albeesonline.com/blog/2008/11/29/warning-setpropertiesruleserverserviceenginehostcontext-setting-property/

Comment: This just delays the warning. It then re-appears later when tomcat deploys the configuration descriptor xml from \workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf\Catalina\localhost

Comment: Your awsome, it worked