# Tomcat 7.0 Http Status 404 issue

Tags: tomcat, http-status-code-404

I am trying run an index.jsp file on a tomcat server through eclipse. However when I run the file I get a HTTP STATUS 404 error. I've checked multiple settings but to no avail. The URL is *http://localhost:8080/LoginApp/index.jsp*
So far what I have checked that I can remember is:

1.web.xml contains index.jsp in the welcome-file

2."Use Tomcat installation(takes control of Tomcat installation

3.*http://localhost:8080* works fine.

4.console reveals a WARNING(not error) with regards to source

```
Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:NewLoginSystem' did not find a matching property
```

5.index.jsp is saved in the WebContent folder.

Any Guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked your web application context root?

Comment: I'm after making a mess of things now. I was getting errors when I changed the setting in server options module. I then decided to delete the server and try a new one. Now the "Use Tomcat installation(takes control of Tomcat installation" setting is greyed out--This problem is fixed....

Comment: @ meewoK what should I be looking for?

Comment: problem is fixed after creating new server?

Comment: The greyed out issue is fixed. the overall problem still exists.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this might solve some else's problem. I don't understand why this was occurring so maybe some one can explain this but I had tomcat running on xampp. By uninstalling tomcat from xampp my index.jsp file loaded as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Your index.jsp file should be within the web-content directory for it to be accessible...

Also have a look at your context root in order to double check the path you should use to access the web application: [How to change context root of a dynamic web project in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437465/java-how-to-change-context-root-of-a-dynamic-web-project-in-eclipse)

Comment: My index.jsp is in web-content directory.

Comment: Just found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278009/warning-setting-property-source-to-org-eclipse-jst-jee-serverappname-did-n . Also, could you try adding a servlet print 'hello world' to verif that is deployed atleast... Did you try http://localhost:8080/LoginApp/index.jsp as well? Are you sure you app is being deployed as LoginApp?