# Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server (404 Error)

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I have a Simple Spring Web Maven project. I'm getting 404 error. I already looked at the following post: [Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:JSFTut' did not find a matching property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566146/setting-property-source-to-org-eclipse-jst-jee-serverjsftut-did-not-find-a)
and [WARNING: Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:appname' did not find a matching property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278009/warning-setting-property-source-to-org-eclipse-jst-jee-serverappname-did-n)

Both of them saying that this is not an error and you can ignore it. They also say you need to specify your `localhost:8080/(aplication-context)`.

**But I can not get rid of the 404 error and can't get any page**. I have tried also creating a web project without maven. Still can't figure it out. Please help me get through this.

Here is my log:

```
Tem 15, 2014 12:58:57 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\Broadcom 802.11\Driver;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files (x86)\SSH Communications Security\SSH Secure Shell;.
Tem 15, 2014 12:58:57 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Tem 15, 2014 12:58:57 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Tem 15, 2014 12:58:57 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 429 ms
Tem 15, 2014 12:58:57 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Tem 15, 2014 12:58:57 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.54
Tem 15, 2014 12:58:57 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor C:\Users\Serhat Can\workspace-spring\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf\Catalina\localhost\SpitterWebMaven.xml
Tem 15, 2014 12:58:57 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:SpitterWebMaven' did not find a matching property.
Tem 15, 2014 12:58:58 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deployment of configuration descriptor C:\Users\Serhat Can\workspace-spring\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf\Catalina\localhost\SpitterWebMaven.xml has finished in 85 ms
Tem 15, 2014 12:58:58 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Tem 15, 2014 12:58:58 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Tem 15, 2014 12:58:58 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 486 ms
```

My web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <display-name>SpitterWebMaven</display-name>

   <!--
        - Location of the XML file that defines the root application context.
        - Applied by ContextLoaderListener.
    -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring/application-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <!--
        - Servlet that dispatches request to registered handlers (Controller implementations).
    -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

My mvc-config.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- Uncomment and your base-package here: -->
         <context:component-scan
            base-package="com.spitter.webs.controller"/> 


    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <!-- Example: a logical view name of 'showMessage' is mapped to '/WEB-INF/jsp/showMessage.jsp' -->
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"/>
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

My application-config.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd">

    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->

    <!-- Uncomment and add your base-package here: -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.spitter.web" />


     <bean id="emf"
             class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
             <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
             <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
             <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.spitter.web.domain"></property>
       </bean>




    <!-- data source to connect mysql db -->
    <bean name="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring_jpa" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>



    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="database" value="MYSQL" />
        <property name="showSql" value="true" />
        <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
    </bean>







    <!-- why do we need this! -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <!-- why do we need this! -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

    <!-- why do we need this! -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf" />
    </bean>


    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />


</beans>
```

Finally my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.springframework.samples.service.service</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpitterWebMaven</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>

        <!-- Generic properties -->
        <java.version>1.6</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>


             <!-- Web -->

             <jsp.version>2.2</jsp.version>

             <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>

             <servlet.version>2.5</servlet.version>





             <!-- Spring -->

             <spring-framework.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>



             <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->

             <hibernate.version>4.2.1.Final</hibernate.version>



             <!-- Logging -->

             <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>

             <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>



             <!-- Test -->

             <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>



       </properties>



       <dependencies>



             <!-- Spring MVC -->

             <dependency>

                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>

                    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>

                    <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>

             </dependency>

             <dependency>

                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>

                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>

                    <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>

             </dependency>

             <dependency>

                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>

                    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>

                    <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>

             </dependency>

             <dependency>

                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>

                    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>

                    <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>

             </dependency>

             <dependency>

                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>

                    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>

                    <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>

             </dependency>

             <dependency>

                    <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>

                    <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>

                    <version>1</version>

             </dependency>

             <!-- Other Web dependencies -->

             <dependency>

                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>

                    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>

                    <version>${jstl.version}</version>

             </dependency>

             <dependency>

                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>

                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>

                    <version>${servlet.version}</version>

                    <scope>provided</scope>

             </dependency>

             <dependency>

                    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>

                    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>

                    <version>${jsp.version}</version>

                    <scope>provided</scope>

             </dependency>



             <!-- Spring and Transactions -->

             <dependency>

                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>

                    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>

                    <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>

             </dependency>

             <!-- AspectJ -->

             <dependency>

                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>

                    <artifactId>aspectjlib</artifactId>

                    <version>1.6.2</version>

             </dependency>

             <dependency>

                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>

                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>

                    <version>1.8.1</version>

             </dependency>

             <!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->

             <dependency>

                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>

                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>

                    <version>${slf4j.version}</version>

                    <scope>compile</scope>

             </dependency>

             <dependency>

                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>

                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>

                    <version>${logback.version}</version>

                    <scope>runtime</scope>

             </dependency>

             <!-- H2 -->

             <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.h2database</groupId> <artifactId>h2</artifactId>

                    <version>1.4.179</version> </dependency> -->

             <!-- MySql -->

             <dependency>

                    <groupId>mysql</groupId>

                    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>

                    <version>5.1.31</version>

             </dependency>

             <!-- Hibernate -->

             <dependency>

                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>

                    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>

                    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>

             </dependency>

             <!-- Apache Commons -->

             <dependency>

                    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>

                    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>

                    <version>3.3.2</version>

             </dependency>

             <dependency>

                    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>

                    <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>

                    <version>2.0.1</version>

             </dependency>





             <!-- Test Artifacts -->

             <dependency>

                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>

                    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>

                    <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>

                    <scope>test</scope>

             </dependency>

             <dependency>

                    <groupId>junit</groupId>

                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>

                    <version>${junit.version}</version>

                    <scope>test</scope>

             </dependency>

             <dependency>

                    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>

                    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>

                    <version>1.9.5</version>

             </dependency>





             <dependency>

                    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>

                    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>

                    <version>1.1.0.Final</version>

             </dependency>

       </dependencies>

</project>
```

**--UPDATE--**

My hello controller (I try to use very basic controller to see if it works. Also, I have hello.jsp in WEB-INF->view):

```
@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

        String message = "Hello World, Spring 3.0!";
        return new ModelAndView("hello", "message", message);
    }
}
```

I have tried lost of url's but here is the default URL that comes when I run the server. -> `/SpitterWebMaven` in local

Another think that I want to add is when I first created the project run on server button was not displaying and I chose Java and Dynamic Web Project to see the run on server button after a research on how to do that.

Comment: It happens if the resource is not available. Can you post your Controller file and also let us know the url that you are trying to invoke

Comment: I added my controller which is very basic HelloWorldController and my url  which is localhost:8080/SpitterWebMaven

Comment: Same thing happened to me, just trying to get the http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_mvc_hello_world_example.htm tutorial to work. Took an embarrassingly long time staring at 404s to discover what @SerhatCan figured out,  that in the "Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:<servlet-name>' " warning, the app is now accessible form localhost:8080/<servlet-name>/hello. Will post back later if I figure anything out but I need to burn off some steam.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to why or how this is happening, but there is a connection between (project properties --> Web Project Settings --> Context Root) and the root url of the dispatchServlet.

Try:

1. Changing Context Root to  other than root url currently available (SpitterWebMaven), which should also be the Servers --> Tomcat ... --> server.xml Server.Service.Engine.Host.Context.path value
2. clean the server and restart
3. You should now be able to access via the  base url also the server.xml Server.Service.Engine.Host.Context.path value should be changed to