# SetProperties issue in Tomcat Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

Today I finished a project of mine that I've been working of for a few weeks. The program is a tomcat 7.0 server that responds to certain http posts.

I had originally started the eclipse project with a silly name which I was planning to change when I was done. So today, I decided to do a last clean-up, add the javadoc, etc - as well as refactoring the project name into something more correct.

This is when I got the following error in Eclipse:

```
[SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:aegis' did not find a matching property.
```

I have searched for solutions to this issue, but none of them I found online helped me resolve it. What I tried:

- Deleting and recreating the Server in Eclipse.
- Redownloading tomcat
- Deleting the .metadata folder in my project.
- Double checked that everything in web.xml is correct (it is).
- Double checked that Everything in the build path is correct (it is).
- Checked that the paths in the Server Overview tab are correct (they are) and that the option "*Use Tomcat Installation*" is selected.
- Tried to run the server with the option "*Publish module context to separate xml files*" enabled (didn't resolve).
- Tried closing the project, create a new dyn. web project and launch it on the server "as is" (to see if the issue is project-related) - but I get the same warning.

At this point I've gone past page 3 on my google searches and I'm just out of ideas.

Any other suggestions? Thanks.

PS: The server doesn't give any other warnings or errors and the last message is `INFO: Server startup in X ms`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to run the below maven command

```
mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0
```

Comment: Please follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278009/warning-setting-property-source-to-org-eclipse-jst-jee-serverappname-did-n