# strange Eclipse compile error

Tags: java, build, compilation, server

All of a sudden, my Eclipse will not compile. I have been using it without any issue for months now making code changes, compiling and testing the change on localhost but suddenly it doesn't like me anymore. After I build my project, republish and restart the server I get the following....  Anyone ever seen this?

```
> Aug 6, 2015 10:14:14 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener
> init INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows
> optimal performance in production environments was not found on the
> java.library.path: C:\Program
> Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program
> Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_45/bin/client;C:/Program Files
> (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_45/bin;C:/Program Files
> (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_45/lib/i386;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\PROGRA~2\CA\SC\etpki\lib;C:\Program
> Files
> (x86)\CA\SharedComponents\PEC\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
> Files (x86)\Microsoft Application Virtualization Client;C:\Program
> Files (x86)\Common Files\M-Tech\;C:\Program Files\Common
> Files\M-Tech\;C:\Program Files (x86)\CA\Cryptography\;C:\Program Files
> (x86)\CA\SCM;c:\Program
> Files\java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin;c:\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin;C:\Windows\CCM\nomad\;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
> Files (x86)\Bitvise SSH
> Client;C:\Users\nc004917\Eclipse\eclipse-with-clearcase\eclipse;;. Aug
> 6, 2015 10:14:15 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule
> begin WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context}
> Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:OIB' did not
> find a matching property. Aug 6, 2015 10:14:15 AM
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init INFO: Initializing Coyote
> HTTP/1.1 on http-8080 Aug 6, 2015 10:14:15 AM
> org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load INFO: Initialization
> processed in 569 ms Aug 6, 2015 10:14:15 AM
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start INFO: Starting service
> Catalina Aug 6, 2015 10:14:15 AM
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start INFO: Starting Servlet
> Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.41 Aug 6, 2015 10:14:15 AM
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start INFO: Starting Coyote
> HTTP/1.1 on http-8080 Aug 6, 2015 10:14:16 AM
> org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on
> /0.0.0.0:8009 Aug 6, 2015 10:14:16 AM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain
> start INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/24  config=null Aug 6, 2015
> 10:14:16 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start INFO: Server
> startup in 860 ms
```

I saw the production environment was not found but, my java.library.path is: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin.  When I run localhost I get the following error.

```
********** Loaded Configurable properties **********
Aug 6, 2015 10:48:24 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jsp.OIBError_jsp._jspService(OIBError_jsp.java:139)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:712)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:824)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:797)
    at org.apache.jsp.Welcome_jsp._jspService(Welcome_jsp.java:335)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Aug 6, 2015 10:48:24 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jsp.OIBError_jsp._jspService(OIBError_jsp.java:139)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:712)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:824)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:797)
    at org.apache.jsp.Welcome_jsp._jspService(Welcome_jsp.java:335)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: Well it says it's started up... where are you seeing an error?

Comment: If the SetProperties is concerning you, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31854936 asked today too...

Comment: Seeing error when I try to pull open localhost webpage. Welcome.jsp should display.  I edited my question to include the error messaging after trying to go to page

Comment: Right - that's more useful. It looks like the SetProperties part *might* be relevant...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution by simply deleting and recreating Server in Eclipse.  Not sure how/why this worked, but it did.  For future users, I also had to do the following:

- Double-clicked Server to open Overview
- Selected "Open Launch Configuration"
- Under Arguments tab, I had 2 missing VM arguments that needed to be replaced after recreating server (-XX:MaxPermSize=1512m -XX:PermSize=512m)