# Spring web project runs with Tomcat in Eclipse fine, but gives 404 when it's on standalone ApacheTomcat server

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, war

I've already deployed one project to standalone server and it works just fine. I took a copy from it to develop another project with the same dependencies. I changed all that needed to be change(think so), and the problem is that project runs just fine in Eclipse with Tomcat, and gives 404 when I try to run it on standalone server.

Is there some specific configuration that need to be done before I export war file?

Unfortunately the standalone server is our school's server so I can't provide any logs from it, because i connect to it using ftp so there is to server console. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you checked that the url is correct?! (It' a silly question but dev's loose their minds from time to time :P)

Comment: Yes i have. I also tried to put the whole path manually, but with no results :( can it be, because of mvc:view-controllr path="/" line? In previous project there were login page. But now the login page is hidden, so only those who knows a link to it can pass there. But still even if that's is the problem why it still doesnt work when i give the path manully.

Comment: And why it runs fine in Eclipse?((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your web app is deployed and registired at tomcat's `manager app gui` at 
`http://localhost:8080/manager/html` for first access you need to configure it go to `tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml` and add the following lines

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui"/>
```

this way you can access the manager app with user:admin, passw: admin

Comment: It gives me nothing when i type http://localhost:8080/manager/html to browser. Ive also noticed that i have Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:palaute' did not find a matching property. in server log in Eclipse, does this mean something scary? :D

Comment: As an error or warning!? see: [WARNING: Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:appname' did not find a matching property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278009/warning-setting-property-source-to-org-eclipse-jst-jee-serverappname-did-n)

Comment: Yes the warning, i already fixed it the way in link you have provided. I've also update the war on server but still with no results

Comment: Wow! Found something, i tried to import my war file back to Eclipse with different name and run in in Tomcat! It gives me now 404 in localhost too

Comment: yeap, that's why I'm telling to open the admin-gui interface so you can see in what name it is deployed if it is at all...

Comment: but i still dont understand how to use ur admin-gui inteface :(

Comment: url to acces app is alwyes proto284.haaga-helia.fi/(war_file_name)

Comment: yes I know it is, and i tried to access it, but there were always 404. I worked fine only with my first project which is tunnit_lila

Comment: Dude your are my saver. Thank You for so quick response! When i tried to import the war ive exported, i noticed in console problem with mariadb driver. I updated a dependence. And now it seems to work. It gives me blank page now, but i think it's because the remote server is still processing my war. So now i know how to simply check wars i will be exporting

Comment: Lol now the problem is that I have blank pages :D App works fine, when i type a secure path, it forwards me to login, but why pages are blank?

Comment: My only suggestion would be to look at your console, this usually  is related to not rendering of the page because of some other error usually in db connection... This is from my experience...

Comment: Isn't there should be 500 error if there is problem with connection?

Comment: Don't really know the error code, but you should look for it when war is being deployed... there may be some short error you're missing....