# Deploying the tomcat 7.0 404 Error

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have using tomcat7.0 in eclipse ide, just crop the image using jsp and servlet.when i crop the image and submit the button the following error will be occured.what i do please find and help.but server will started.

```
    INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor web_site.xml from E:\Mecherie_project  \.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf\Catalina\localhost
Nov 4, 2011 8:40:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'source' to   'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:web_site' did not find a matching property.
Nov 4, 2011 8:40:14 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Nov 4, 2011 8:40:14 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Nov 4, 2011 8:40:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 483 ms
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `<form action>` URL is likely wrong. Pay attention to the URL in your browser address bar while seeing the 404 after submit. Is that URL right? Sure? It should be exactly the URL which matches the URL pattern of the servlet.

Please note that the logs which you have there are **irrelevant** to the concrete problem. If you worry about this one warning, please read this related question: [Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:JSFTut' did not find a matching property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566146/setting-property-source-to-org-eclipse-jst-jee-serverjsftut-did-not-find-a).

Comment: Thank u BalusC,I got the output