# Java Spring Runtime error

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I'm getting this error while running my application in eclipse by tomcat

```
[SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Project' did not find a matching property.
```

As a result I'm getting resource not found error in browser

I also wanted to know, is this  is what causing 404 error

Comment: Similar Q has been asked before : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566146/setting-property-source-to-org-eclipse-jst-jee-serverjsftut-did-not-find-a

Answer (score -1):

Seems like there's a problem with you eclipse setup.

I know it can be hard to set up Spring in eclipse. There are a lot of ways to mess it up and produce unexpected errors.

Instead of learning the exact reason why you install failed I suggest looking into a eclipse verison with spring built in. The creators of spring understood the possible difficulties associated with their product and generously created a Spring Tools Suite here's a link, https://spring.io/tools

I strongly suggest you use STS for all your spring related development... As they(the creators) also suggest on their site.

Comment: @rohin seems like it can just be a warning shown above, either way get STS and consider using it. It is the recommend spring tool.

Comment: You don't need STS to run a Spring application nor any IDE. Relying on STS/Eclipse will lead you to not understand issues when deploying an application in production where there is just a Tomcat and no IDE...

Comment: @Gaël So what? Learning more about tomcat is more important that learning all errors associated with spring eclipse integration. I am not here to argue with you if you believe that STS is a bad tool tell the spring developers not to support it.