# 404 with simple java servlet/html form

Tags: java, forms, tomcat, servlets

**ED: this question is not a duplicate. the alleged duplicate makes no mention of the error that was in my console, and the solution to my problem is not found in the linked question.**

i'm using [derek banas's tutorials](http://www.newthinktank.com/2012/05/java-video-tutorial-42/) to learn servlets right now. or at least, i'm trying to! i keep encountering a 404 error when i submit my form.

here is my code. first, the java class:

```
package helloservlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Lesson41
 */

@WebServlet
public class Lesson41 extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */ 

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String usersName = request.getParameter("yourname");

        String theLang = request.getParameter("Language");

        int firstNum = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("firstnum"));
        int secondNum = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("secondnum"));
        int sumONum = firstNum + secondNum;

        response.setContentType("text/html");

        PrintWriter output = response.getWriter();

        output.println("<html><body><h3>Hello " + usersName);

        output.println("</h3><br />" + firstNum + " + " + secondNum);
        output.println(" = " + sumONum + "<br />Speaks " + theLang + "</body></html>");
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Lesson41</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>helloservlets.Lesson41</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Lesson41</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Lesson41</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="US-ASCII">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form method="post" action="http://localhost:8080/Lesson41/">

        What's your name?<br /> <input name="yourname" /><br /> First
        Number <input name="firstnum" /><br /> Second Number <input
            name="secondnum" /><br /> <input type="hidden" name="Language"
            value="English" /><br /> <input type="submit" />

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

in my console, i am getting this warning:

```
WARNING: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Lesson41' did not find a matching property.
```

and that's the only warning i'm getting. i googled it and followed the advice i found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104854/setpropertiesrule-warning-message-when-starting-tomcat-from-eclipse), but it hasn't fixed my problem.

thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16683950/354831) answer will help you.

Comment: this does address my question, but the explanation from @GiDar actually helped me understand how eclipse deploys the application. thank you for the links!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the url in the form is correct? `http://localhost:8080/Lesson41/`
If you are using Eclipse, by default it deploys your application as `http://localhost:8080/[Your-Project-Name-Here]/Lesson41/`

Comment: thank you so much! you were right! i think i got confused because both the project name and the class name are the same!