# eclipse webapp welcome file display error

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, web-applications, welcome-file

I m new to eclipse and facing difficulties at the beginning of a new webapp.
index.jsp doesnt display.

[image]

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

<display-name>PizzaOrderApp</display-name>

<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I already tryed with http://localhost:8080/PizzaOrderApp/index.jsp and http://localhost:8080/PizzaOrderApp/jsp/index.jsp

after remove-readd tomcat server:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the .jsp file directly in the WebContent folder rather than creating a folder for the JSP pages?

Comment: yes. already tried that. i guess problem is on web descriptor or tomcat config side. unfortunately i m not familiar with that one.

Comment: Are you getting any error in the console? If so.. What's the error

Comment: 2 rows may have the cause:

WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:PizzaOrderApp' did not find a matching property.

INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path:

Comment: This is a warning.. your not getting any errors? And the solution to the warning is  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104854/setpropertiesrule-warning-message-when-starting-tomcat-from-eclipse

Comment: @Istvan Did you try deleting the server completely, Clean the project and running the project from scratch again?

Comment: oh, and there were no errors in the console. just there warnings.

Comment: @Istvan Oh ok. Let me know if anything comes up.

Comment: same issue after removing and readding server (updated with screenshot). is there a way in eclipse to specify the initial relative path for the webapp, similarly to netbeans?

Answer (score 0):

You did not define the [Spring dispatcher servlet](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html) in web.xml. You can either copy index.jsp outside of WEB-INF directory (into webcontent), or you should have a deep look into the [Spring MVC documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html).

Answer (score 0):

> I also faced this problem but what i was doing wrong is, I created
>   Dynamic project in eclipse with Dynamic Web Module version 3.0. It
>   won't give you Web.xml file.I added Web.xml file from other project
>   but still Welcome File is not getting.
>
> Then i deleted the project and i created the project with Dynamic Web
>   Module Version 2.4 and it given me Web.xml file. I again Configure the
>   Welcome File in the Web.xml file, After that its working fine.Server
>   which i am using is Tomcat 7 and java 1.7,Eclipse Luna.
>   [image]